# Stop the camera from moving up while character is jumping

Tags: actionscript-3

mcMain is my character and this is the enterframe eventlistener

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);

function cameraFollowCharacter(evt:Event){
root.scrollRect = new Rectangle(mcMain.x - stage.stageWidth/2,     mcMain.y - stage.stageHeight/2, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
```

I have two problems -

1) My character is always in the center. I want to position it down.
2) Whenever the character goes up the camera also goes up to follow the character. I want this to happen when he goes left or right but not then when he jumps.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you obviously don't know what that code does actually. Anyway, I'd suggest to replace `mcMain.y` with a constant value.